# Стоит ли работать над legacy проектами?

Tags: java, spring, работа

Я начинающий Java разработчик, 4 месяца, как устроился на свою первую работу в одну крупную известную компанию. В целом в этой компании меня все устраивает - зарплата, красивый офис, местоположение, прочие плюшки. Смущает только одно - я попал на, скажем так, legacy проект: java 7, struts 1, сложная и запутанная архитектура, в которой черт ногу сломит. Никаких тебе спрингов и прочих модных-молодежных технологий.

Стоит ли оставаться на этом проекте и работаь на нем ощутимое время? Не аукнется ли то, что у меня фактически нет коммерческого опыта  работы с актуальными фреймворками в дальнейшем? Домашние пет-проекты на стеке spring (core, mvc, security, spring boot) я писал, но я так понимаю это не то. Может это не такая уж и проблема и освоить новые для себя технологии разработчику с опытом не сосавит особой проблемы? Или все-таки пытаться перевестись куда-то на другой проект?

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий и зависит от мнений. А так - поработайте на легаси, получите опыт "работания", перейдете в другой проект и вперед!

Comment: java и легаси - две стороны одной монеты))). привыкайте. заодно и узнаете что и как работает под капотом а не вот это вот все. а потом уже можно будет и на стильно-модно-молодежно)

Comment: Там еще проблема в том, что проект очень большой и сложный, одно обучение, чтобы просто допустили к нему длится несколько месяцев. То есть тут нельзя будет просто пройти оплачиваемое работодателем обучение, поработать немного и свалить. Это будет очень не красиво.

Answer (score 7):

Не занимаюсь Java. Пишу на PHP.

Аукнется тем, что на следующем месте будут спрашивать по новью. И собеседующие могут не понимать, что фреймворки - не главное, и перестроиться на что-то другое не сложно. Просто вопрос времени.

Развивайте свои пет-проекты на новых технологиях. Набирайтесь опыта на легаси, порой это бесценный опыт :). Откройте новый проект на работе на новом стеке. Смените работу через 1-2-3 года.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, хотя ИМХО пет проекты на джаве - такое себе. Тут смысл именно в том, чтоб проект был большим, боевым и высоконагруженным. Могу ошибаться.

Comment: @fonzy, высокая нагрузка не везде. например, есть внутренние проекты компании, они могут быть сложными, но не нагруженными. если нужно "большим, боевым", возьмите горячую проблему в отрасли, решите ее, выпустите под GNU GPL. Это - секрет успеха Nginx. Иногда даже достаточно скомпоновать часть "своего" кода и чужие сервисы, в этом поможет Docker. Мой пример: есть проблема с подписанием ЭЦП документов - установка ПО сложная, документация убогая. Я написал несколько оберток над этим и понятную документацию с примерами, положил в докер контейнер. Четыре звезды на гитхабе :)

Comment: @fonzy вы с хайлодом в своей жизни вообще возможно никогда не столкнётесь. Не нужно сильно на таких вещах зацикливаться)